# db Query fails when field value starts with a number

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, slim

I am running into an interesting issue. I am using Angular with PHP Slim and Mysql. My select query is failing due to one column in the db. the column is `uid` and it is a varchar(110).

It is filled with unique IDs some start with letters and some start with numbers. I have concluded that when I remove the rows with uid's that start with numbers it works.

NOTE: I don't have this issue on my local machine running MAMP.

Could Slim be interpreting the field wrong? if so does anyone know how to fix this. I do not know Slim at all

EDIT:

```
require '.././libs/Slim/Slim.php';
require_once 'dbHelper.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
$db = new dbHelper();

// stats
$app->get('/stats', function() { 
    global $db;
    $rows = $db->select("trackclicks","id,action,platform,value,firstname,lastname,email,uid,timeclicked",array());
echoResponse(200, $rows);
});

**HELPER FILE**  
function select($table, $columns, $where){
    try{
        $a = array();
        $w = "";
        foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
            $w .= " and " .$key. " like :".$key;
            $a[":".$key] = $value;
        }
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("select ".$columns." from ".$table." where 1=1 ". $w);
        $stmt->execute($a);
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(count($rows)<=0){
            $response["status"] = "warning";
            $response["message"] = "No data found.";
        }else{
            $response["status"] = "success";
            $response["message"] = "Data selected from database";
        }
            $response["data"] = $rows;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        $response["status"] = "error";
        $response["message"] = 'Select Failed: ' .$e->getMessage();
        $response["data"] = null;
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: why are you using slim if you dont know slim?

Comment: good question and I don't have a good answer. I was looking for a Angular tutorial that used PHP and MySql. I came across this one that used Slim for the PHP Restful API

Comment: how about posting the 'slim' code

Comment: I have edited the original post with the code. NOTE this does not include the Slim library